# how to make css animations play simultaneously regardless of when it starts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I have a situation where I multiple divs can have a class with a css animation, but in my situation the classes represent a state. Since these can change, the state that uses the css animation can be set onto the div at a different time than another div. With the yellow blinking effect I now have for that state, you see the multiple divs blink at different moments instead of together simultaneously.
So the question is, is there a way to make it so that the divs start blinking on the same moment instead, like that you can start the animation at .000 milliseonds?

I have added a snippet to simulate my problem:

```js
function changeState(id) {
  let stateElement = document.getElementById(id);
  stateElement.classList.remove('green');
  stateElement.classList.add('yellow-blinking');
  stateElement.innerText = 'WARN';
}

setTimeout(() => changeState('state1'), 459);
setTimeout(() => changeState('state2'), 1321);
setTimeout(() => changeState('state3'), 2778);
```

```css
    .state {
      margin: 8px;
      padding: 4px 0px 0px;
      border: 2px solid #000000;
      border-radius: 3px;
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 20px;
      width: 80px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
   .yellow-blinking {
        background: #ffff00;
        color: #000000;
        animation: yellowflash-small 1s linear 0s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: yellowflash-small 1s linear 0s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes yellowflash-small {
        0% { background: #ffff00; }
        49% { background: #ffff00; }
        50% { background: #ffffff; }
        99% { background: #ffffff; }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes yellowflash-small {
        0% { background: #ffff00; }
        49% { background: #ffff00; }
        50% { background: #ffffff; }
        99% { background: #ffffff; }
    }

    .green {
       background: #00d200;
       color: #000000;
    }
```

```html
<div class="state green" id="state1">OK</div>
<div class="state green" id="state2">OK</div>
<div class="state green" id="state3">OK</div>
```

As you can see, the blinking is not synchronised with each other. Is there a way to make them blink together, regardless of when it gets to that state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the animation initially to the element and animate only the `background-color` then use `background-image` to have the initial green color. Like that the animation will start running behind the green and we simply show it by removing the green layer

```js
function changeState(id) {
  let stateElement = document.getElementById(id);
  stateElement.classList.remove('green');
  stateElement.innerText = 'WARN';
}

setTimeout(() => changeState('state1'), 459);
setTimeout(() => changeState('state2'), 1321);
setTimeout(() => changeState('state3'), 2778);
```

```css
.state {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 4px 0px 0px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: yellowflash-small 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes yellowflash-small {
  0% {
    background-color: #ffff00;
  }
  49% {
    background-color: #ffff00;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  99% {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
}

.green {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#00d200 0 0);
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="state green" id="state1">OK</div>
<div class="state green" id="state2">OK</div>
<div class="state green" id="state3">OK</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but somehow in my code the animation keeps playing despite the green class being added to the div. I'll try and see if I can make this work if I rewrite other parts of my code

Comment: @DanielvanDommele check well the green class in my code, It's background-image